How can vscode set a shortcut to fold code exactly like webstorm
vscode does not recursively fold code the same way webstorm does. After you fold the code, when you expand it, you cannot return to the line where the cursor was when you folded the code. I need to set it to the same operation as webstorm's default collapse and expansion code block, please tell me how to set vscode's shortcut key.
Thank you
